# Force one config to be imported before another?

Tags: 8, configuration

Hitting an issue when installing a site from config and I think the order of operations may be the issue. Is there some way to ensure that one config is imported before another one?

Edit: sorry, guess this wasn't specific enough for some people. Issues are:

- encryption profile set up with the encrypt module/key/real_aes
- encryption enabled in relaxed module
- error during installation of relaxed config settings because the encryption entities provided by encrypt don't exist yet.
- setting encrypt as a dependency didn't seem to solve my problem
- realizing that maybe I'd need to add real_aes as a dependency as well

Comment: By manually adding it as a dependency?

Comment: What issue?????

Comment: Lol @laymannx, added some more details

Comment: What error?????

Comment: I made the topic very general on purpose so that it applied to more situations than only mine. If you really want to know the exact issue it's `ResponseText: TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\encrypt\EncryptService::decrypt() must implement interface Drupal\encrypt\EncryptionProfileInterface, null given, called in /site/modules/contrib/relaxed/src/SensitiveDataTransformer.php on line 78 in Drupal\encrypt\EncryptService->decrypt() (line 64 of /site/modules/contrib/encrypt/src/EncryptService.php` and addressed more specifically in https://www.drupal.org/project/relaxed/issues/3064077

Comment: Also just a general note that the "?????" feels a bit rude and unnecessary to me. Discussion around here should be kept civil.

Comment: Sorry it was just to reach the character limit.

Comment: @leymannx fair enough, thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm already using Config Split for this site, so as a workaround I've added the problematic dependent config to the various split directories. This seems to have done the trick, but still curious if there are any other methods available.